# Best way to store equations and images in database to be displayed later as pdf and html

Tags: html, mysql, pdf, latex, mathjax

I am planning to create a database to store multiple-choice questions.  Every question will have 5 parts: first, the question body, and the rest four, the four choices (stored in 5 different columns of the database).  Each row of the table will contain information about one question.  The question body and choices contain:

1. Plain Text

   Mathematical Equations

   Diagrams (png or jpeg)

Later, these questions will be fetched from the database to be displayed in the following:

1. Formatted PDF files

   Web portal

I am thinking of storing the question and its image path (similarly, options and their image paths) as separate columns in database.  Text and equations would be stored after being formatted as LaTeX text in the table directly.  Later,

1. **For PDF files:** Documents in pdf format could be directly created by fetching the questions from the database and using pdflatex.

   **For web portal:** Converting the text using htlatex and rendering equations using mathjax and then displaying each question on the web-portal.

Is this the best method to achieve this and is there any other format in which the questions could be saved in the database?

PS:  The formatting of the question and equations is very critical for me, and hence I prefer LaTeX for this job.

Comment: For question/answer formats that are latex have you considered using a latex service to dynamically generate an image? You could just store the markup and have the latex generated when needed with no need to store the images.

Comment: Yes, I have. I will be using XyMTex/chemfig for chemical structures and TikZ for diagrams.  But the questions may still contain diagrams which would be too difficult to generate from LaTeX, so I have kept it as an option.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open word document
   Insert a table
   Then type questions (that contain maths equations and chemical structures) in one cell
   The choices in other cells one by one in the table

   Save the  document as web page,filtered( saving in this format does not save word formatting)
   Now a web page is created with a folder that contains your equations and chemical structures as images
2. Now upload the web page

   Also upload the images created in the folder to your web site
3. Parse the HTML Document

   [Find code vb.net in web sites](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1040510/Grab-and-Parse-HTML-Data-Through-POST-in-Csharp)
   get the `<tr>` nodes and all its `<td>` nodes . Get the innerHTML for the `<td>` nodes and save them to database table fields
4. To Display questions- just fetch the html content and place them within div tags (innerHTML)